# Spring Boot Security Login

Tags: https, spring-security, spring-boot

My enhanced Pet Clinic application requires security.

I want to have the following:

- Login form - WORKING
- HTTPS - WORKING
- HTTP requests redirecting to HTTPS - not sure how to do this
- HTTP static resources - not sure if this is really necessary

Any advice would be welcome.

My application can be found at https://github.com/arnaldop/enhanced-pet-clinic.

Here's code from my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter subclass:

```
private static final String[] UNSECURED_RESOURCE_LIST =
    new String[] {"/", "/resources/**", "/assets/**", "/css/**", "/webjars/**",
        "/images/**", "/dandelion-assets/**", "/unauthorized", "/error*"};

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(UNSECURED_RESOURCE_LIST);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //@formatter:off
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(UNSECURED_RESOURCE_LIST)
                .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/owners/**", "/vets/**", "/vets*").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/manage/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest()
                .permitAll()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
        .and()
            .requiresChannel()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/owners/**", "/vets/**", "/vets*", "/manage/**")
                    .requiresSecure()
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/router?q=unauthorized")
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                .expiredUrl("/login?expired")
        ;
    //@formatter:on
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: arnaldo, no way to reach you except this -- downloaded your excellent pet clinic have some suggestions/potential bugs if u are interested.

Comment: Sure, sounds good. arnaldopiccinelli at Gmail. Someone else pulled the project and got an error I need to look at also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "HTTP requests redirecting to HTTPS - not sure how to do this"

we will need to add the TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean to one of our @Configuration classes.

```
@Bean
  public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
          SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
          securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
          SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
          collection.addPattern("/*");
          securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
          context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
      };

    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(initiateHttpConnector());
    return tomcat;
  }

  private Connector initiateHttpConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    connector.setScheme("http");
    connector.setPort(8080);
    connector.setSecure(false);
    connector.setRedirectPort(8443);

    return connector;
  }
```

for more information please refer [this link](http://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/)